# How to Run Page Speed Insight Test via API from a specific location

Tags: pagespeed

I am looking to automate the process of running Page Speed Insight tests via API for multiple URLs. While I have successfully automated the process, I am struggling to find a way to conduct these tests from my local region in Asia. The scores I receive from the API are significantly lower compared to when I run the tests locally, as the Page Speed Insight defaults to using the United States as the testing location.

A solution to run it from any location

Answer (score 0):

This isn't [an option in the API](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rest/v5/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed).

PSI attempts to run from your location, so if testing from an Asia data centre then it should the closest available data centre. However even that is not guaranteed as it will use the other locations if a location is unavailable or under load.

As an alternative you ca just run Lighthouse yourself using [Lighthouse-CI](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci) from your own servers and cal the [CrUX API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/api/) if you want the CrUX data that PSI also returns.